# WCF CustomPeerResolverService not working with no LAN connection

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am using a CustomPeerResolverService (running in a windows service which hosts it in a ServiceHost) with a number of peers on a peer to peer network. My server address is,

net.tcp://127.0.0.1/Server

The idea being that the server and peers would work on a local machine when there was no network connection.

I have extended the CustomPeerResolverService class so I could see what was going on, and what actually happens when there is no LAN connection is that the peers call the Resolve method, which is asking "Are there any other peers, and how can I find them", but they never call the register method.

This means that the server is always saying 'no there are no other peers' because none of the peers actually registered themselves.

Overall this results in connections between the peers and the resolution service, but never any connections between peers.

When I switch on my LAN connection the register method is called by each peer, and everything works properly.

I noticed something though, each peer had two TCP connections to the CustomPeerResolverService when the LAN was enabled, but only one when it was disabled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a loopback adapter, it is used for testing things that assume a network when there is no network.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839013